# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: (app keeps on crashing)

Tags: android

```
 Process: com.example.ucic.startup2, PID: 10917
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.example.ucic.startup2; is package not installed?
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1069)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.example.ucic.startup2; is package not installed?
        at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:889)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1057)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-01-15 15:32:50.650 1925-1945/? E/NetdConnector: NDC event {613 IfaceClass idle 0 1534431617640} took too long: 670ms
2019-01-15 15:32:54.289 1925-1925/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-01-15 15:32:54.321 1925-1925/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-01-15 15:33:11.647 1925-1939/? E/ActivityManager: Aborting stack trace dump (current extra pid=9860); deadline exceeded.
2019-01-15 15:33:11.685 1925-1939/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.android.systemui
```